# How to convert RxJS triple 'of(...).pipe.map(...)' expression to the Observable of three dimensional array

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have this expression:

```
var s2 = of(6, 16, 26).pipe(
    map(v1=>of(5, 15, 25).pipe(
      map(v2=>[v1,v2])
      )), 
    combineLatestAll());
  s2.subscribe(console.log)
```

... and s2 is an of type `Observable<number[][]>`as I want it.

Can I convert the following expression in a similar way to `Observable<number[][][]>` (instead of it being an `Observable<Observable<number[]>[]>`):

```
var r2 = of(5, 15, 25).pipe(
    map(v1=>of(6, 16, 26).pipe(
      map(v2=>of(7, 17, 27).pipe(
        map(v3 => [v1,v2,v3])
        )))),
    combineLatestAll());

   //Print the output:
    r2.subscribe(e1 => {
  e1.forEach(e2 => {
    e2.subscribe(e3 => {
      console.log(e3);
    });
  })
});
```

I can't get my head around it. Any help appreciated.

Solution suggested by Ruth:

```
let s3: Observable<number> = of(5, 15, 25);
let s4: Observable<number> = of(6, 16, 26);
let s5: Observable<number> = of(7, 17, 27);

const r1 = s3.pipe(
  map((v3: number) =>
    s4.pipe(
      mergeMap((v4: number) =>
        s5.pipe(
          reduce((acc: number[][], v5: number, i5: number) => {
            acc[i5] = [v3, v4, v5];
            return acc;
          }, [])
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  combineLatestAll()//reduce((acc: number[][], curr: number[][]) => [...acc, curr], [])
)
r1.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: why you need observable ? you just use plain javascript for this kinda sync operation

Comment: It's just for learning RxJS purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could use just `toArray()` operator but it's pretty hard to wrap my head around the nested calls so I'm not sure this is what you wanted :):

```
var r2 = of(5, 15, 25).pipe(
  map(v1=>of(6, 16, 26).pipe(
    map(v2=>of(7, 17, 27).pipe(
      map(v3 => [v1,v2,v3]),
      toArray(),
  )))),
  combineLatestAll());
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-veofem?devtoolsheight=60

... or if you want to avoid the nested Observable you'll need `mergeMap`:

```
var r2 = of(5, 15, 25).pipe(
  map(v1=>of(6, 16, 26).pipe(
    mergeMap(v2=>of(7, 17, 27).pipe(
      map(v3 => [v1,v2,v3]),
      toArray(),
      )))),
  combineLatestAll());

r2.subscribe(e1 => {
  e1.forEach(e2 => {
    console.log(e2);
  })
});
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-riquzh?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: You are the champion - it works the way I expected it. The only problem is that `r2`is still not of type `Observable<number[][][]>` but the type of `Observable<Observable<number[][]>[]>` - I don't understand why?

Comment: I think it cannot be type `Observable<number[][][]>` because then you wouldn't be able to subscribe to the Observables in the top level array with `e2.subscribe(e3 => {...})`. Or your goal was to avoid the nested `subscribe()` completely? Check my update.

Comment: Yep. I wanted to avoid nested subscribe and just call `console.log(r2);`

Comment: Then you can use `mergeMap`, I updated my answer.

Comment: You are true genius. I need some time to digest your code but it does exactly what I wanted it to do. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: #martin Martin why do I need operator toArray() to convert map(v3 => [v1,v2,v3]) to two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

something like below, your `combineLatestAll()` only works for the first level map that's why it returns the wrong result. I prefer mannually control the execution of observable with `mergeMap`,`switchMap` etc

```
of(5, 15, 25)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((v1) =>
      of(6, 16, 26).pipe(
        mergeMap((v2) => of(7, 17, 27).pipe(map((v3) => [v1, v2, v3])
        ))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: The original function I provided works just fine. It produces the expected latest values (`combineLatestAll()` works just right) - your code just merges all three arrays. My original question was if I can create the code somehow that returns `Observable<number[][][]>` though. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: i ran your code it logs [Observable, Observable, Observable] though

Comment: My apologies. I have just added to the original code the the code that prints the values - . It starts with `r2.subscribe...` - please try it out.

Comment: The way that you get your return value is anti pattern e.g the nested subscription, the answer given is returning `Observable<number[][][]>`

Comment: What do you mean by `the answer given is returning Observable<number[][][]>` - that is what I want, the `Observable<number[][][]>` but I am getting `Observable<Observable<number[]>[]>` instead. How can I code it to get the result of `Observable<number[][][]>` ?

Comment: I mean the answer i posted is given `Observable<number[][][]>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, IMO this is rather a relatively difficult exercise to learn RxJS. Nevertheless, in addition to the solution provided by @martin, you could try to use the [`reduce`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce) with [`concatMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap) operator to manually set the array.

Note that `reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], [])` is synonymous to the `toArray()` operator.

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { concatMap, reduce } = rxjs.operators;

const jsonEditor = document.getElementById('json-editor');
const textContainer = document.getElementById('text-container');

const options = {};
const editor = new JSONEditor(jsonEditor, options);

let s3 = of(5, 15, 25);
let s4 = of(6, 16, 26);
let s5 = of(7, 17, 27);

s3.pipe(
  concatMap((v3) =>
    s4.pipe(
      concatMap((v4) =>
        s5.pipe(
          reduce((acc, v5, i5) => {
            acc[i5] = [v3, v4, v5];
            return acc;
          }, [])
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], [])
).subscribe({
  next: (response) => editor.set(response),
  error: (error) => textContainer.innerHTML = error
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/jsoneditor@9.4.1/dist/jsoneditor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jsoneditor@9.4.1/dist/jsoneditor-minimalist.min.js"></script>

<div id="json-editor" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
<span id="text-container"></span>
```

#### Update: Typescript

```js
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, reduce } from 'rxjs';

let s3: Observable<number> = of(5, 15, 25);
let s4: Observable<number> = of(6, 16, 26);
let s5: Observable<number> = of(7, 17, 27);

s3.pipe(
  concatMap((v3: number) =>
    s4.pipe(
      concatMap((v4: number) =>
        s5.pipe(
          reduce((acc: number[][], v5: number, i5: number) => {
            acc[i5] = [v3, v4, v5];
            return acc;
          }, [])
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  reduce((acc: number[][], curr: number[][]) => [...acc, curr], [])
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gdklkl?file=index.ts)

Comment: Thanks for help. I can't compile your code - it complains at the line with `acc[i5] = [v3, v4, v5];` saying `(parameter) v3: number
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Comment: @JanuszDalecki: I've updated the post with a typed example. I don't know how you're implementing it. If the error persists, please show what you're trying. Or better try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Now this line `"reduce((acc: number[][], curr: number[][]) => [...acc, curr], [])"` displays the error `No overload matches this call.` The example in my question and the answer by Martin contain complete working code - they just don't include import statements. What I am trying to do is to merge three Observables produced by the `of` operator and then combine the latest ones only.

Comment: BTW how did you insert the code in your comment `Update: Typescript` that looks so professional - I spent a lot of time trying the same without any success

Comment: @JanuszDalecki: I just looked into the examples from @martin. He doesn't seem to merge all the arrays into one single array at the end which I'm currently attempting. May be you don't even need the 2nd `reduce` statement. Try removing it. Also like mentioned in the answer, you could also try replacing the 2nd `reduce` operator with `toArray()` operator.

Comment: @JanuszDalecki: About your formatting question, sure. There is a [handy markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from SO. However I prefer just to click the `Edit` link on posts to see how they are formatted. I don't save the edit obviously rather just cancel after taking a look. You could also try hitting `Edit` of my answer.

Comment: I have done few changes to your code and it works exactly as expected with one subscribe call - congratulations. I don't know how to insert that code in the comment. Every time I try to use CTRL-K to insert the code in comment my chrome search google opens. I would like to share that code with you as this is exactly what I wanted - to print the correct results by one console.log statement. I have appended that code at the end of my question so you can have a look at it.  I titled it `Solution suggested by Ruth`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What does `reduce((acc: number[][], v5: number, i5: number)...` do ? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @JanuszDalecki: I get what you're trying now. The `reduce((acc: ...` statement is analogous to the JS [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function. It applies the callback function to each emission of the observable in order (denoted by `v5`), and returns a single-value (denoted by `acc`). The `i5` in the RxJS `reduce` operator denotes the number of the emission. The `[]` is the seed value for the accumulator.

Comment: How do you know that the `number`  inside `reduce` operator is two dimensional ([][]) array. Can that be deduced from the number of `map` operators minus one `mergeMap`?

Comment: @JanuszDalecki: The see value `[]` implies the `acc` initially is of type `any[]`. The statement `acc[i5] = [v3, v4, v5]` implies that each element of `acc` holds it's own array of type `any[]`. So the resulting `acc` type is `any[][]`. And from our explicit initialization we know that the type is `number` and not `any`. So the type is `number[][]`.